# Changing a value on a record in Ruby on Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my controller and I am wondering how I might add the current_user.id to the ingredient. I am new to ruby and am still learning the syntax, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def create
  @ingredient = Ingredient.new(ingredient_params)
  @ingredient.user_id = @decoded_auth_token.id

  if @ingredient.save
    render json: @ingredient, status: :created, location: @ingredient
  else
    render json: @ingredient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end 

private

# Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
def ingredient_params
  params.require(:ingredient).permit(:title, :quantity, :unit)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
def create
  @ingredient = current_user.ingredients.new(ingredient_params)

  if @ingredient.save
    render json: @ingredient, status: :created, location: @ingredient
  else
    render json: @ingredient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

That, naturally, assumes that `User has_many :ingredients` and `Ingredient belongs_to :user`.

BTW, I don't know why you have a `$` in front of `$current_user.id`. What is that all about?

Based on your comment, I suspect you're going about things the wrong way. Presumably, you have:

```
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

So, in `ApplicationController`, you could either (1) save your `token` to an instance variable, in which case it would be available in `IngredientsController` or (2) save it to the `session`, in which case it would also be available to `IngredientsController`.

I think it's not great to have `current_user` represent a `token`. That could lead to confusion for the future you. If I were you, I'd name the `token` variable something like, oh, I don't know, say, `autenticated_token` or even just `token`. Then, I would use `current_user` to hold an actual `User` instance (that you look up, presumable, using the `token`) so that you can do your `current_user.ingredients.new(ingredients_params)` business.

Also, I don't know what your design parameters are. But, I would speculate that you want to have `User` and `Ingredient` have a many-to-many relationship. Otherwise, you're going to end up with a lot of `Ingredient` records with the same name (like, 'egg') - assuming, naturally, that a lot of users have egg ingredients. Just a thought.

Based on your edit, I see you've changed:

```
@ingredient.user_id = $current_user
```

to:

```
@ingredient.user_id = @decoded_auth_token.id
```

I would guess that `@decoded_auth_token.id` != `current_user.id`. If you're `@decoded_auth_token` has a `user_id`, I would guess that you would want to use that, instead. Something like:

```
@ingredient.user_id = @decoded_auth_token.user_id
```

I suppose if `Token belongs_to :user` (or whatever your token class name is), then you could do:

```
@ingredient = @decoded_auth_token.user.ingredients.new(ingredient_params)
```

But, then I think you're getting sideways with the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter#In_object-oriented_programming). And you never want to get sideways with the Law.

I still prefer:

```
@ingredient = current_user.ingredients.new(ingredient_params)
```

But I suppose that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I am handling authentication in the application controller and it decodes the json web token in there. I needed a way to retrieve the user_id from that token in another controller e.g., the ingredients controller.

Comment: current_user is actually a token and not the users record from the database, so this does not work.

Comment: Thanks! I re-worked it and realized I had the token available in the ingredients controller already. So I revised the question above. Imo I think I am best with how it is now. I want to keep track of each user's ingredient inventory. If I have two eggs it is okay, as long as they belong to different users. But as far as setting the user_id on the newly created ingredient do you have any ideas given this new information?

Comment: I hear what you're saying about each user having their own egg. But, what happens when you want to find all users that have an egg ingredient?

Comment: Thank you. I added it to the session and that fixed the problem. Way better than having a global variable. What you are saying about the database might be useful, and would definitely reduce the database size. I'm looking up many to many now.

Comment: Sure thing. Feel free to accept if you feel so inclined to help future searchers. BTW, the M2M thing is pretty trivial (you'll just need a `UserIngredient` class and a couple of `has_many` and `has_many :through` directives). It seems like an appropriate DB normalization exercise, IMO. But, again, depends on what you're up to. BTW, to handle something like `quantity`, I would add that as a field on the `UserIngredient` model.

Comment: Actually now that I am thinking about it. I have a quantity on the ingredient. So each user has a different quantity. So they are all very unique.

Comment: Person A might have 4 eggs, and B have 3 eggs.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. See my edit to my comment. I would make that a column on the `UserIngredient` table. But, you know, what floats your boat.